# Does EntitiyListener run in same Thread?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, entitylisteners

I have an Entity which is annotated with

```
@EntityListener(MyListener.class)
```

In the class MyListener, I have an Method annotated with

```
@PrePersist
```

Inside this method, do i have the same thread which did the change on the Entitiy? Or can it be another thread? I have stored some information on the thread that do the change on the entity and i want to access this information in the listener.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will always be the same thread. From the JPA spec (v2.2):

> An entity manager must not be shared among multiple concurrently
>   executing threads, as the entity manager and persistence context are
>   not required to be threadsafe.

The entity manager is only used from a single thread (or you have a bug), so the same must apply to the entity.